# Camera2 API can't turn off TORCH mode

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have some code for a camera app that allows the user to toggle some flash options: `OFF`, `ON`, `TORCH`, `AUTO`, and `RED_EYE`. When the user swaps the mode I have the following switch statement:

```
when (flash) {
    Flash.OFF -> {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
    }
    Flash.ON -> {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH)
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
    }
    Flash.TORCH -> {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
    }
    Flash.AUTO -> {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH)
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
    }
    Flash.RED_EYE -> {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE)
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
    }
}
```

Clicking the button just iterates through these, so everything is working great until the user gets to `TORCH`. The flashlight turns on and all is fine, then the user clicks one more time to switch to `AUTO`, but the light doesn't go off. Only when the user clicks enough times to get to `OFF` will the light go off.

I got this from https://github.com/google/cameraview/blob/master/library/src/main/api21/com/google/android/cameraview/Camera2.java#L544 which by the way also breaks in the same manner.

I've also creating an issue at https://github.com/google/cameraview/issues/259 to help gain visibility for this issue.

Do I have to start a new capture session with flash off before coming off `TORCH`? Is there a better way?

UPDATE:

As suggested I've added a `TorchCallback` and got the following results though I can't make much sense of them. These come it when I start the first capture session and never change as I toggle the flash mode.

```
onTorchModeChanged(0, false)
onTorchModeChanged(0, false)
onTorchModeUnavailable(0)
onTorchModeUnavailable(0)
```

Comment: To better understand what's going on maybe try to implement [TorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.TorchCallback) to get an event if the torch is disabled for some reason while you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer for how to fix it but not yet why this is needed. I've updated the method to include the following block before the switch statement

```
if (builder.get(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE) == CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH &&
        flash != Flash.TORCH) {
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
    captureSession.capture(builder.build(), null, null)
}
```

What this is doing is setting the flash mode to off if the current builder's flash mode is torch and the new mode isn't. We run `capture` because it takes priority over `setRepeatingRequest`. Also, `setRepeatingRequest` says that calling more than one of these in a row will cancel the former.